How to measure overshoot of an op-amp without having an oscilloscope
I need to measure the overshoot of an op-amp but have no oscilloscope or other measuring device available. I should therefore have a circuit to do so. I have created an input pulse and want to apply it to the input of the op-amp. To avoid having to use a very high sampling rate ADC, I thought  I could use a peak detector at the output:
The problem is the value of C1 needs to be changed with every op-amp(U1) that is changed. and also when the Q2 is changed from the ideal model, the results change.
The yellow curve is the output of U1.
What's a better peak detection approach or method to measure overshoot?

I don't think the second opamp has high enough bandwidth to handle this.

how would you verify the correct operation of the detector circuit without a scope?


... and also when the Q2 is changed from the ideal model, the results change

That's because the transistor appears in the transfer function which means the overshoot and even the settling time will change.
Of course you can design a fast peak detector (AD must have a collection of circuit somewhere on the web including fast amplifiers and peak detectors) but, if this is for characterising then maybe you should first make sure the overshoot and oscillatory settling do not come from anything introduced by the external components at the output (the transistor itself, and the D2's body resistance) because, for example, a series RC at the output introduces a pole and this may reduce the phase margin, hence the overshoot and few cycles of ringing with settling.
